# What lifetime scope to use when using an instance in a separate thread?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, autofac

I have a WebApi project and in a controller I'm using `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` to start a job in a separate thread:

```
public IHttpActionResult DoJob()
{
    HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(ct =>
    {
        var service = new MyService(logService, userInfo);
        var entity = service.DoJob(ct);
    });

    return Ok();
}
```

Currently, in the above I'm using a concrete instance (which I want to replace) of my service . I also use `Autofac` and for my services, I configured as follows:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
    .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .InstancePerRequest();
```

The above registration works fine for all services when using normally within a request.

Will the above registration also work for services when run in a separate thread after the request terminates?

Comment: if you say `new MyService()` you aren't using dependency injection/autofac.

Answer (score 0):

> Will the above registration also work for services when run in a separate thread after the request terminates?

Yes the *configuration* for the *registration* will work.

Whatever method you call in your service may or may not work:

[What this means is that if you try to resolve components that are registered as instance-per-request but there’s no current request… you’re going to get an exception.](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#instance-per-request).

Either one of two following cases are correct.

> You might get autofac to work sometimes, because the request still exists, but sometimes won't because the request ends.

or (most likely)

> the execution of `QueueBackgroundWorkItem()` is outside the lifetime scope so it won't work at all.

So ultimately your service should create it's own lifetime scope (IDisposable etc etc).

Answer (score 0):

Dependency injection is nothing to do with thread, unless we missed to configure the dependency injection of all the accessible members of that thread at the start of the application/service.